# Inserting some lines in btw a file using Python

Tags: python

My intention is to add some lines in between certain lines that matches some criteria (the criteria is not straight forward, and is derived from the code logic). 
I used tell() function to get the location where the new lines are to be put. Also, I saved the text portion until this position, and the rest of file in two lists, using readlines() as below.

This way, I planned to add the new lines to the first list and then append with the second list, so that I could write them together to the original file.

```
fp.open("path", "r")
<some logic to find where the new lines are to be inserted>
insertPos = fp.tell()
firstPart = fp.readlines(insertPos)
secondPart = fp.readlines()
firstPart.insert(len(firstPart)+1, newLines)
newContent = firstPart+secondPart)
fp.writelines(newContent)
fp.close()
```

But the issue is that,
when readlines() is done using the first output of tell(), to put the merged list, its not pointing to the correct line in the file. It moves some more lines ahead. i.e.firstPart is not exactly splitting at insertPos.
Is there anything that I'm missing here? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic would be much easier if you just read the whole file into a list, then modify that list and write it out.

Here, we add the whole list `lines_to_add` at location `loc` using slice notation:

```
lines = fp.readlines()
new_lines = lines[:loc] + lines_to_add + lines[loc:]
```

Then just write it out.

Comment: This just solved all my issues! made my code so simple and shorter. But does it slow down the execution? The script now takes almost the double time than before. Anyways, thx a lot for the guidance..

Answer (score 2):

If the files aren't huge, I would do this instead of messing with buffer positions:

```
lines = list(open(filename))
i = ... # figure out what line you want to insert before
lines.insert(i,new_line)
open(filename,'w').write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: The files are huge (20K lines etc). Will that be a problem with logic (I havent try this yet)?

Comment: 20k lines, if the lines are on average 100 characters, that's like 2mb. I bet you're fine.

Comment: @Murph is right. Also, under the hood, python has to rewrite the entire rest of the file even if you're using tell and seek.

Comment: @AbhiV If you need this to be fast, flat files and lines isn't the right data structure.

Comment: No, execution time isnt an issue and this is a one time file conversion activity. So, efficiency is not a big issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. Let me try this out. Looks like this will be just what i need.